# Google Sheet MultiDrop Down Comma Delimiter

Tags: google-sheets, dropdown

i am trying to create a Multi DropDown in google sheet separated by comma.
i want to enter the TYPE,FLAVOUR,QTY.

Example:
TYPE A,ABC,0.5,TYPE A,GTH,1

right now i have individual dropdowns and then use concatenate function to combine the values then copy paste them into the resulting cell.

Requirement:

1. single drop down where i can start typing TYPE,FLAVOUR,QTY and it can atut complete.
2. if i select TYPEA, only the flavours corresponding to flavour A will showup in drop down.
3. source data is in a different tab to the dropdown.

attaching example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Iu08a6nt_KkT-cyA4IcQuzJVgpwlWsVnP8KCP-rRpBo/edit?usp=sharing

many thanks for your help in advance.
let me know if you have any queries.

i have tried a solution mentioned here but there is a lot of lag
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/128693153/multiple-selection-in-drop-down-menu?hl=en